# Amazon Redshift: "*SELECT* 1" vs. volt_dt_0 vs. volt_tt_51343b6aa3bd4

Tags: subquery, explain, redshift

I've noticed subqueries in Amazon Redshift can be represented in the explain plan in 3 separate ways:

```
-> XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 1"

-> XN Subquery Scan volt_dt_0

-> XN Seq Scan on volt_tt_51343b6aa3bd4
```

"SELECT 1" and volt_dt_0 seem to be the same thing, so:

1. Why the different naming convention?
2. If they're not the same thing, what is the difference and when is one used over the other?

volt_tt_51343b6aa3bd4 seems to mean the subquery has been executed in a CREATE TEMP TABLE statement. It seems conceptually similar to CTEs. A few questions here:

3. When is this chosen over "SELECT 1" or volt_dt_0?
4. The additional CREATE TEMP TABLE query shows up in SVL_QLOG as a separate record from the main query. Does the elapsed time in the record for the main query include the elapsed time for the CREATE TEMP TABLE subquery?
5. Canceling the main query doesn't seem to cancel the CREATE TEMP TABLE sub query. Is this true?
6. Why does running EXPLAIN require that the CREATE TEMP TABLE subquery to be executed? (maybe because of #7?)
7. It looks like statistics are being gathered on the temp table if STATUPDATE ON (padb_fetch_sample queries are being run). Is this true?